# Why doesn't GruntJS break execution if exception is thrown?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, inline, uglifyjs

I'm exploring [grunt-inline](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline) module and faced with the following problem. I have the following task's config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  inline: {
    options: {
       uglify: true
    },
    dist: {
      src: 'src/index.html',
      dest: 'dist/index.html'
    }
  }
});
```

From the config above `uglify: true` option means executing `UglifyJS.minify` on [this line](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline/blob/master/tasks/inline.js#L133):

```
var c = options.uglify ? UglifyJS.minify(inlineFilePath).code : grunt.file.read( inlineFilePath );
```

The problem is that if `UglifyJS.minify` throws exception (which I'm just faced with) the `grunt inline` command will not fails but exits quite.

So, either the problem with this module of lacking some grunt's flags from my side?

It would be great if you could explain me how to break grunt execution on any exceptions.

**EDIT:**
Also I've noticed that if I catch exception and re-throw it myself it breaks grunt well, like the following:

```
try {
    var c = options.uglify ? UglifyJS.minify(inlineFilePath).code : grunt.file.read( inlineFilePath );
} catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
}
```

So why does't exception from `UglifyJS.minify(inlineFilePath).code` break gruntjs task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the module. I can't seem to find a way to flag and return these errors. You could try replace that line with:

```
var c;
if(options.uglify){
    try{
        c = UglifyJS.minify(inlineFilePath).code
    }catch(err){
        grunt.log.error(err);//catch error and send to grunt
    }
}else{
        c=grunt.file.read( inlineFilePath );
}
```

**UPDATE:**
So why does't exception from UglifyJS.minify(inlineFilePath).code break gruntjs task?

Looks like this is an issue with the error itself: `JS_Parse_Error`
This is not a properly constructed error and is not caught by grunt. Looks like you have to catch it yourself and wrap it in a `new Error()` as you have done above until a fix goes in. See link below:

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/348

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why if I can catch exception from `UglifyJS.minify` it's not break grunt? See my updated post please

Comment: Grunt only handles exceptions that are attached to the grunt object.The grunt object should be used to communicate with gruntjs. http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt

Comment: It's a little bit not true. As I described in my post's update above, grunt breaks fine if I throw exception by myself.

Comment: You're right issue is with the error thrown itself. see update.

Comment: Thank you for the researching!